# Excel VBA how to automatically accept IF a message box appears

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am running a macro which refreshes imported data each minute. The data is drawn from a URL however sometimes it is unable to open it due to poor connection.

Then a message box appears :

> "unable to open http:..."

and I have to click OK in order for it to continue.

It does not always do this as mostly it can access the data but as this needs to be running throughout the day in the background I can't be watching it 24/7 to click OK and keep it going.

Is there anyway I can edit the code to include something like :

```
If MsgBx appears
Sendkeys ~ (enter)
```

I have tried `DisplayAlerts = False` which doesn't work. 
And there is no way to improve the connection to prevent error from occuring in first place.

If it can't access the data I just want it to leave it, move on, and try again in the next minute batch.

Have spent ages searching these forums and have not found the answer anywhere. 
Any ideas much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you paste the relevent parts of the code here, you might get a better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to trap the error directly by using error handling :

Place this line at the top of your code :

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

And these at the end, right before the `End Sub` :

```
    Exit Sub 
ErrHandler: 
    Select Case Err.Number 
    Case Is <> "1004" 
        MsgBox "Error number - " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description 
    Case Else 
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") 
        Resume 
        Goto Retry 
    End Select
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting an error of "Label not defined" for GoTo Retry. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to specify that... You need to place `Retry:` on the line before your URL query (or before the code you want to relaunch if it has failed)

Comment: Cool thank you! I think its working but will only know by leaving it running a while and waiting for non-existent error messages to pop up

Comment: Sure, you'll have to see later of there wasn't any issues, just let me know and **if it work plz accept answer to mark your issue a solved**! :)
And remember to **use up/down vote** when you browse and find useful/useless posts! ;)

Comment: One error after nearly an hour of updating every minute. I'm happy! Changed the TimeValue to 00:00:10 to give it a bit more of a chance. Thanks for your help R3uK. (sorry can't use the up/down arrows, don't have enough "reputation points". New to VBA and to this forum!)

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't worry for vote, you'll use it later after earning a few more rep points! ;) Enjoy SO and VBA!^^